# Is that possible to get backup from VPS by Shell access?

Tags: shell, ssh, gzip, vps, kloxo

My VPS is going to die and i want to move to temporary hosting, but my Control panel is KLOXO which means it's such a pain to compress files because it will crash during Zipping large files.

I just have access to kloxo and also SSH from terminal, and i was wondering if you guys know a  way to zip files in root and download it as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this might help. Compress your file using zip/tar utilities and then You can use scp to transfer those files on to your local machine. In case you prefer GUI tools you can also use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (a Windows GUI based client) to transfer your files.

```
scp your_username@remotevps.com:backup.zip /some/local/directory
```

To zip directory called pics in your home directory (/home/you/pics), type the following command:

```
zip -r backup.zip /home/you/pics/
```

Using tar:

```
tar -zcvf archive-name.tar.gz directory-name
```

Explanation:

```
-z: Compress archive using gzip program
-c: Create archive
-v: Verbose i.e display progress while creating archive
-f: Archive File name
```